# Specific string value extraction using Formula

Tags: formula-field

Need help in creating a formula to get 'src' value from  image url (rich text area) value. Here is the IMAGE url value

```
(SDLC_Output__c:{IMAGE_SDLC__c=<img alt="User-added image" src="https://pra--PERSONAL11--c.cs16.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=aByf00000004CAu&amp;feoid=00Nf0000001Khvs&amp;refid=0EMf0000000D2qU" style="height: 474px; width: 500px;"></img><br>Tetsunjkdjshfbc})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your format does not change, you should be able to use the following formula below. Below you'll see that I'm truncating your overall string by 2 attributes, "style" and "src", after this, there is a few additional subtractions which will remove unwanted blank spaces and quotes. **That being said, Long text areas are not supported (this also includes rich text area)**. It will only work with standard text. If you really need this to be on long text areas, you'll need to convert the formula into a trigger.

```
RIGHT(
    LEFT(
        SDLC_Output__c,
        FIND("style=", SDLC_Output__c) - 3
    ),
    LEN(
        LEFT(
            SDLC_Output__c,
            FIND("style=", SDLC_Output__c) - 3
        )
    ) - FIND("src=", SDLC_Output__c) - 4
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I realized it later formula field won't work but Rick Text area field , so now i'm using Process builder and this formula works perfectly